# CodeIgniter: How to send array from model to controller, then view

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have the following model:

```
            // Session info in $session array.
            $session = $query->row_array();
            $userid = $session['uid'];
            $uq = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `administration_users` WHERE id = $userid");

            $now = strtotime(date("m/d/Y h:i:s A"));
            if($session['terminatedate'] > $now) {

                // If Session is STILL ACTIVE, let's give them an additional hour. Have fun!

                $newterm = $now + 3600;

                $userq = $uq->row_array();
                $username = $userq['username'];
                $userfull = $userq['name_first'] . " " . $userq['name_last'];

                $this->ELog->authentication('INFORMATION',$username,"Session for $userfull has been extended by 3600 seconds (1 hour) due to activity in application.");

                $this->db->query("UPDATE `administration_sessionkeys` SET terminatedate='$newterm' WHERE id='$session[id]'");

            } elseif($session['terminatedate'] < $now) {

                // If Session is OVER...

                $userq = $uq->row_array();
                $username = $userq['username'];
                $userfull = $userq['name_first'] . " " . $userq['name_last'];

                $this->ELog->authentication('INFORMATION',$username,"$userfull has been logged out automatically by AuthLogger due to session timeout. Thanks for stopping by. Goodbye!");

                $this->db->query("UPDATE `administration_sessionkeys` SET `terminated`='1',`terminated_details`='Session Ended. Thanks for stopping by. Goodbye!' WHERE id='$session[id]'");
                setcookie("ssmp_auth_cookie_uid", "", time() - 3600);

                return false;

            }

            $userinfo[] = $uq->row_array();
            return array($userinfo);
```

My controller, looks like this:

```
    $this->load->model('Auth_model', "", TRUE);
    $data = array($this->Auth_model->authcheck());

    if(!$data) {
        header("Location: /auth/login");
    } else {

    $this->load->view('tmpl/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('dashboard', $data);
    $this->load->view('tmpl/footer', $data);

    }
```

My view is as such, and the problem here is that I can't access my array from the model in the view. What am I doing wrong? I've been racking my brain for 3 hours now on this. I need a break and some help.

```
<title>Logged into SSMP as <?=$id;?></title>
```

This should give me the "id" column in the array, right? No?

Please help me out here, sorry for so much code, I wasn't sure what you guys needed to see in order to help me out.

Thanks for all that are able to provide assistance with this irritating issue.

Scott

Comment: First of all make sure that you have data in `$data`, check with `print_r($data)`

Answer (score 0):

[`row_array()`](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html) already returns an associative array, so you don't need to wrap the results in an array again

change

```
$userinfo[] = $uq->row_array();
return array($userinfo);
```

to

```
$userinfo = $uq->row_array();
return $userinfo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the following :

```
$userinfo[] = $uq->row_array();
return array($userinfo);
```

to :

```
return $uq->row_array();
```

and :

```
$data = array($this->Auth_model->authcheck());
```

to :

```
$data['administration_users'] = $this->Auth_model->authcheck();
```

In you view file :

```
<title>Logged into SSMP as <?php echo $administration_users['id']; ?></title>
```

Tips: use redirect helper for redirection :

```
if(!$data) {
  // header("Location: /auth/login");
  // Assuming that you have url_helper already loaded,
  // if not, uncomment the next line :
  // $this->load->helper('url');
  redirect('auth/login');
```